# spring mvc placeholder not print with <spring:input> tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I created a form with spring framework. For every field, I created a placeholder attribute. My problem is that for the input tag called 'streetNumber' in the address.jsp file, it doesn't print the value of the placeholder but the '0' value.

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

Address.java :

```
public class Address {
    private String streetName;
    private int streetNumber;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    public String getStreetName() {
         return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
         this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public int getStreetNumber() {
         return streetNumber;
    }
    public void setStreetNumber(int streetNumber) {
         this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    }
    public String getZipCode() {
         return zipCode;
    }
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
         this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
    public String getCity() {
         return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
         this.city = city;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
         return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
         this.country = country;
    }
}
```

AddressController.java :

```
@Controller
public class AddressController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/address",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView init(){
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("address");
            modelAndView.addObject("address",new Address());
            return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/address",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView validate(@ModelAttribute("address") Address address, BindingResult result){

              return new ModelAndView("address");
     }

}
```

Address.jsp :

```
<forms:form method="post" modelAttribute="address" action="/address">
      <spring:message code="streetName" var="streetName" />
      <forms:input path="streetName" id="streetName" placeholder="${streetName}" />

      <spring:message code="streetNumber" var="streetNumber" />
      <forms:input path="streetNumber" id="streetNumber" placeholder="${streetNumber}" />

      <spring:message code="zipCode" var="zipCode" />
      <forms:input path="zipCode" id="zipCode" placeholder="${zipCode}"/>

      <spring:message code="city" var="city" />
      <forms:input path="city" id="city" placeholder="${city}" />

      //rest of the code

 </forms:form>
```

MessageBundle.properties :

```
addressBtnText = Adress
gpsBtnText = GPS
homePageTitle = Geo Accessibility - HomePage
streetName = Street
streetNumber = NÂ°
zipCode = Zip Code
city = City
selectCountry = Select a country
adressValidateBtn = Confirm
backButton = Back
AccessibilityIndexTitle = Accessibility index
graphicResult = Graphic Results
completeResult = Complete Results
typingAdressUrlTitle = GeoAccessibility - Type your address
accessibilityResultUrlTitle = Accessibility Index
mapTitle = GeoAccessibility - Graphic Results
accessibilityResultTitle = "GeoAccessibility - Results"
```

Comment: Since you defined `streetNumber` as an `int` type in your Domain class, it will default to '0'.  If you want to have the input default to "blank", then make the `streetNumber` of type `java.lang.Integer`, which is the wrapper class for `int`.  Word of caution: If you are using an `@InitBinder`, you may have to set it to allow nulls for Integer classes.

Comment: Is forms:input, the jsp input tag from "Spring Framework JSP Form Tag Library" (`uri=http://www.springframework.org/tags/form`)?

Comment: Yes, `forms:input` is the Spring JSTL tag.  It will create an input field of type text that is bound to the specified Model Attribute.